# Termine per riferirsi alla lingua italiana assieme ai suoi dialetti

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, single-words

Che termine posso usare per riferirmi all'insieme della lingua italiana standard assieme a tutti i sui dialetti?

Grazie.

Comment: Giusto per chiarire: i *dialetti* non sono davvero dialetti (nel senso di varianti di una data lingua, come possono essere l'American English o l'Australian English per l'inglese) ma lingue indipendenti (la cui relazione con l'italiano è simile a quella tra *Scots* e inglese o tra catalano e castigliano). Detto questo, domanda interessante!

Comment: Sì, siate lieti di cogliere questa domanda con tutte le sue sfumature! :-)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Non sono sicuro di questa distinzione fra “lingue” e “dialetti”. Secondo un ragionamento come [questo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dialetto/), mi sembra che i *dialetti* italiani siano proprio dialetti (poi ci sono il sardo, il siciliano e altre lingue, ovviamente). Semmai sottolineerei la distinzione dei vari livelli di italiano, italiano regionale, dialetto regionale e dialetto locale. Oppure, semplicemente, le lingue sono dialetti con un esercito e una marina...

Comment: @DaG Senza entrare nei dettagli, sono d'accordo che la distinzione tra lingua e dialetto è sfumata nel migliore dei casi. Tuttavia alcuni cosiddetti dialetti (e.g. il Veneto) hanno una letteratura e sono stati la lingua ufficiale di una nazione per secoli, per cui relegarli a "varianti dell'italiano standard" mi sembra un po' troppo riduttivo. Nessuno oserebbe chiamare lo Scots o il catalano un dialetto...

Comment: Da un certo punto di vista, forse ci sono in Italia tanti modi antichi di parlare anche perché c'è stato un certo livello di ispirazione tra un posto è un altro, magari una volta la gente si spostava di meno, o per motivi storici o anche per altri motivi non legati alla storia. Io questo non lo so. Sta di fatto che il livello di diversità sia sugli accenti, sia moderno che antichi, sia sulla grammatica e intonazione e modo di esprimersi diverso da un posto all'altro in Italia, come sicuramente anche in altri posti, è eccezionale.

Comment: @DaG: Il problema forse è che non si tratta dell'italiano e "***i suoi***" dialetti, ma dell'italiano e i dialetti italiani (nel senso di dialetti parlati in Italia).

Comment: Ben detto, forse si può dire di più, ma si può anche dire così. Antichi, nuovi, e tutti e due.

Comment: Mi dispiacerebbe veramente, però, che qualcosa andasse perso.

Comment: Comunque, a parte tutti questi commenti, se qualcuno potesse rispondete questa domanda in concreto...

Comment: Grazie delle risposte. Mi è piaciuto leggere.

Answer (score 4):

Le lingue italiane. Si può anche fare differenza tra i dialetti italiani (i dialetti/lingue parlati in Italia) ed i dialetti dell'italiano (che hanno origini toscane).

Guarda questo articolo: [articolo](http://www.homolaicus.com/linguaggi/lingue_italiane.htm)

> i cosiddetti dialetti italiani sono tutti lingue che si sono sviluppate in modo autonomo e diverso rispetto al fiorentino che ha costituito la base per l'italiano standard

Comment: Grazie per la risposta. Forse sarebbe bene dare nella risposta anche gli estremi dell'articolo che citi; è bene che una risposta sia più possibile autosufficiente, in caso dovesse sparire la pagina citata, per esempio.